# What happened to Jonny Quest's mother?

Tags: jonny-quest

The **Jonny Quest** franchise has been around for over 50 years. In most versions, Dr. Benton Quest is a widower, effectively being Jonny and Haji's legal guardian, while Race Bannon takes a more active part in the protecting and raising. In some versions, Race's daughter Jessie, of similar age to Johnny and the slightly older Haji, is also there.

We know Mrs. Quest is dead (adding to the "missing mom" trope), and I *think*  Jessie's mom may just be divorced from Race, but we never find out what happened specifically to either of these women... at least, I have no memories of those episodes.

I know there have been comic books and other media, so I was wondering, has anything been mentioned specifically as to how Mrs. Quest died, what her first name was, and what, if anything, happened to Jessie's mom?

Comment: https://jonnyquest.fandom.com/wiki/Rachel_Quest